# When try to do df.fillna() but get errors

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, kaggle

When I work on Titanic dataset, I try to fill the NaN value in Age column:

```
for tuples in data.itertuples():
    if np.isnan(tuples.Age) and tuples.Title == 'Master':
        tuples.Age.fillna(age_median['Master'],inplace=True)
```

but I get error as below:

```
'float' object has no attribute 'fillna'
```

Is there any way can fix this ?

Comment: The issue is that you're trying Pandas methods on a tuple, which of course won't work. A general piece of advice is that you very rarely need to actually iterate through a pandas dataframe. This is no exception: `data[data["Age"].isna() & data["Title"] == "Master", "Age"] = data[data["Title"] == "Master", "Age"].median()`. Here I'm saying "For the rows where Age is NA and Title is Master, set the column Age to the median Age of Masters".

Comment: could you show a example of your dataframe? you don't need loops here

Comment: @alkasm Thanks for your solution, I figure it out!